# Do we have $\oplus_{i=1}^d M_i\cong \sum_{i=1}^d M_i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M_i$ submodule of a module $M$ (over $R$). Do we have $$\bigoplus_{i=1}^d M_i\cong \sum_{i=1}^d M_i\ \ ?$$

I think yes, and my proof goes as follow.

Let \begin{align*}
\Phi: \sum_{i=1}^d M_i&\longmapsto \bigoplus_{i=1}^dM_i\\
m_1+...+m_d&\longmapsto (m_1,...,m_d). 
\end{align*}
This is clearly a $R-$module morphism. The surjection is obvious. For the injection, $$0=\Phi(m_1+...+m_d)=(m_1,...,m_d)=0\implies m_i=0,$$
and thus $\Phi$ is bijective what prove the claim.

Is it correct ? Does it also work if $d=+\infty $ ? If yes, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty M_i=\{m_1+m_2+...\mid\text{ where $m_i\neq 0$ for  only a finite number of }m_i\}\ ?$$

Because in my course, the definition of semi-simple module $M$ is if $$M=\sum_{i=1}^d M_i$$
where $M_i$ are simple. Then I have a remark that say that we can take the sum infinite, and then, I have a proposition that say that $M$ is simple iff $M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^d M_i$ where $M_i$ are simple. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Your submodules must have trivial intersection, otherwise $\Phi$ is not well defined. For example take $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb R$ and observe that $ \Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R\cong \Bbb R^2\not\cong \Bbb R =\Bbb R + \Bbb R$. But, if the intersection is trivial, the proof goes through.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli There isn't a map defined to begin with.

Comment: @egreg Ops... I read it backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the proof is incorrect.

There is a surjective homomorphism the other way around:
$$
\sigma\colon\bigoplus_{i=1}^d M_i\to\sum_{i=1}^d M_i,
\qquad
\sigma(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)=x_1+x_2+\dots+x_d,
$$
which in general is not an isomorphism.

For instance, with $d=2$ and $M_1=2\mathbb{Z}$, $M_3=3\mathbb{Z}$ as submodules of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the direct sum is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, whereas the sum is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Your attempt at defining a map is incorrect, because an element $x\in\sum_i M_i$ can be represented in distinct ways as
$$
x=x_1+x_2+\dots+x_d=x_1'+x_2'+\dots+x_d'
$$
with $x_i,x_i'\in M_i$, for $i=1,2,\dots,d$.

Just think to vector spaces and you'll immediately find other examples.

As another example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ has infinitely many subspaces of dimension $1$. Their sum is just $\mathbb{R}^2$ and is surely not direct.